# How to send a list object from inside another list object in Node.js and Express

Tags: json, node.js, express

I am developing a REST API using node.js and express framework for the first time. I am struggling to fix a very small issue in Node.js and Express, but however, i am unable to do so. I have checked online for all the possible solutions and tried with what all options i know but i am unable to figure out the syntax for the same.

**Background** : I have one object named “Restaurant” and another object named “Menu” which has a foreign key reference to “Restaurant”.

Now, i have a requirement (common scenario), where i need to send a response to client in the below json format,

```html
{
  "Restaurants": [
    {
      "restaurantid":"5ad36b55c26b685030335e30",
      "restaurantname": "ABC Restaurant",
      "menus":[
         {"menuname":"item1", "menucost":"10"},
         {"menuname":"item2", "menucost":"20"}
    },
    {
      "restaurantid":"9sd72b55c26b685030335e31",
      "restaurantname": "XYZ Restaurant",
      "menus":[
         {"menuname":"item3", "menucost":"10"},
         {"menuname":"item4", "menucost":"20"}
    }
  ]
}
```

**Problem** - I am unable to figure out how to **build** the "menus" object in node.js and append it to my "menus" variable. I am able to send a response from a single table without any issues. **Issue is only when i need to send the menu list based on restaurantid.**

I need to get the menus based on the restaurantid.

Below is the code which i am using for returning data from mongodb.

```html
router.get('/', checkAuth, (req, res, next) => {
    Restaurant.find()
        .exec()
        .then(docs => {
            res.status(200).json({
                count: docs.length,
                restaurants: docs.map(doc => {
                    return {
                        _id: doc._id,
                        restaurantname: doc.restaurantname,
                        menus: ????? <<**This is where i am stuck. Not able to figure out how to write the syntax**>>
                    }
                })
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            });
        });
});
```

Please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that MongoDB is designed to store hierarchical documents with relational links between independent collections being something of an afterthought, this seems more like a schema design problem. A menu belongs to a single restaurant (since even individual franchises of a larger chain may have their own modifications or restrictions), so `Menus` could well work better as a property *of* `Restaurants`. It'd certainly be easier for your use case here since you wouldn't need to build anything. If you do need to look at menus alone you can always `db.Restaurants.find({...}, {menus: true});` to project just that field.

Comment: Hi dmfay, sorry if my code snippet is confusing. My menus are specific to each restaurant only. In other words, each restaurant has its own menus. I have grouped all of them into one object named as "Restaurants". I have both restaurant and menus in separate tables and menus has a foreign key reference to restaurant.

Comment: From my frontend, i will be adding Restaurants from a separate page and Menus from a different page by selecting the Restaurant Name from the dropdown in menus page. I am just trying to give as much info as possible.

Comment: What I'm saying is that what you're trying to do will be both easier and more in line with how MongoDB works with data if Menus _aren't_ separate from Restaurants but rather belong to them explicitly.

Comment: Do you mean, i need to save "menus" list in the restaurant object itself in mongodb inside a "menu" property?? How can i do that using Node? Can you point me to the right direction/link?

Comment: It's a document -- just set `someRestaurant.menus = ...` and save it.

Comment: I did not realize that one. Thanks a lot for the suggestion and prompt responses. I will implement it and mark this as answer.